# How can add extra Firebase Cloud Functions to an Angular Unviersal project

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

In an Angular Universal project this is the fixed `firebase.json` setting:

```json
{
    "hosting": [{
        "target": "PROJECT-ID",
        "public": "dist/PROJECT-ID/dist/PROJECT-ID/browser",
        "ignore": [
            "**/.*"
        ],
        "headers": [{
            "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
            "headers": [{
                "key": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }]
        }],
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "function": "ssr"
        }]
    }],
    "functions": {
        "source": "dist/PROJECT-ID"
    }
}
```

[image]

But now, I would like to add extra Firebase Cloud Functions (both HTTP and callable), so I would like to struct this server folder to code functions with typescript, src-folder, `tsconfig.json` and so on. This is easy if you start from scratch:

[image]

Can anybody help me? I am not sure if I have to add the functions in my `index.js` file and deploy SSR and the remaining functions together, or do I have to create another folder for functions, and deploy first SSR and later other functions?

Comment: you want to use ssr and cloud functions both? or ssr as cloud functions?

Comment: Both. I am already using SSR as Cloud Function (deployed in Firebase)

Comment: This may help you.
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-5-universal-firebase-4c85a7d00862

Comment: Thanks, @T.SunilRao, but in that link is explained how to get SSR as Cloud Function (what i have), but not how to add more extra Cloud Functions to my project. What I have done is create another project (associated with the same firebase-project, with "functions" feature), and I am deploying that functions apart from the first project.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions for AngularFire is contained in the @angular/fire/functions module namespace. Import the AngularFireFunctionsModule in your NgModule. This sets up the AngularFireFunction service for dependency injection.

Im not sure if this can help you [Deploy your application on Firebase Hosting & Functions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md)